# Keycloak cannot create user in LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, keycloak

After upgrading to Keycloak 22.0.3 I have setup an LDAP connection through which I'd like to manage users via the Keycloak Admin API. Getting users, roles, groups works as expected but creating a new user fails with

```
{ "errorMessage": "Could not create user" }
```

According to the logs the root cause is

```
javax.naming.directory.InvalidAttributeValueException: [LDAP: error code 21 - 00000057: LdapErr: DSID-0C0910E6, comment: Error in attribute conversion operation, data 0, v3839]; remaining name 'cn=username,OU=User,OU=company,DC=domain,DC=at'
```

I checked the LDAP schema for the username (Directory String) so I think this should be working. However I am really not an LDAP expert and can't really tell whether this is is an LDAP or Keycloak issue.

Any help appreciated, I have gone through all related questions without being able to solve this time-consuming issue.